# Set group permission on folder

Tags: active-directory, permissions, powershell, access-control-list

I have a folder with lots of subfolders

- D:\Data\Subfolder1
- D:\Data\Subfolder2
- D:\Data\Subfolder3
- D:\Data\Subfolder4
- D:\Data\Subfolder5
- ...

I need to create three active directory groups for each subfolder like this.

- FS_Data-Subfolder1_Read
- FS_Data-Subfolder1_Change
- FS_Data-Subfolder1_Full

and after this is done i have to map folder, Activedirectory group, and permission.

To set the permission is the hard part. this is how far i got. i dont know how to bind the group to the permission and then apply it to the folder.

```
$SharePath = "\\fs\data\"
$FSGroupPath = "OU=GROUPS,OU=Data,DC=DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL"

Get-ChildItem $SharePath | ForEach-Object {
$GroupNameRead = "FS_Data-" + $_ + "_Read"
$GroupNameChange = "FS_Data-" + $_ + "_Change"
$GroupNameFull = "FS_Data-" + $_ + "_Full"

New-ADGroup -Name $GroupNameRead -DisplayName $GroupNameRead -GroupScope DomainLocal -GroupCategory Security -Path $FSGroupPath -Description "Ger Läs Rättigheter till sökväg: FS\Data\$_"
New-ADGroup -Name $GroupNameChange -DisplayName $GroupNameChange -GroupScope DomainLocal -GroupCategory Security -Path $FSGroupPath -Description "Ger Ändra Rättigheter till sökväg: FS\Data\$_"
New-ADGroup -Name $GroupNameFull -DisplayName $GroupNameFull -GroupScope DomainLocal -GroupCategory Security -Path $FSGroupPath -Description "Ger Fulla Rättigheter till sökväg: FS\Data\$_"

$set_Group   = $GroupNameFull
$set_rights = Modify
$acl = Get-Acl $SharePath
$permission = $set_user,$set_rights,"Allow"
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $permission
$acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
$acl | Set-Acl $SharePath


}
```

Answer (score 2):

See if [this example from Don Jones](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.02.powershell.aspx) helps you:
You basically take the existing acl object from the folder, add a new rule to it (SetAccessRule), and the rule contains the principal(user or group,the right and whether it's an allow or deny). The updated aclobject is then applied to the file/folder using set-acl.

```
#ChangeACL.ps1
$Right="FullControl"

#The possible values for Rights are 
# ListDirectory, ReadData, WriteData 
# CreateFiles, CreateDirectories, AppendData 
# ReadExtendedAttributes, WriteExtendedAttributes, Traverse
# ExecuteFile, DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles, ReadAttributes 
# WriteAttributes, Write, Delete 
# ReadPermissions, Read, ReadAndExecute 
# Modify, ChangePermissions, TakeOwnership
# Synchronize, FullControl

$StartingDir=Read-Host "What directory do you want to start at?"
$Principal=Read-Host "What security principal do you want to grant" `
"$Right to? `n Use format domain\username or domain\group"

#define a new access rule.
#note that the $rule line has been artificially broken for print purposes.
#it needs to be one line. the online version of the script is properly
#formatted.
$rule=new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($Principal,$Right,"Allow")

foreach ($file in $(Get-ChildItem $StartingDir -recurse)) {
  $acl=get-acl $file.FullName

  #Add this access rule to the ACL
  $acl.SetAccessRule($rule)

  #Write the changes to the object
  set-acl $File.Fullname $acl
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you specify the `-PassThru` parameter on the `New-ADGroup` cmdlet, it returns the new group. The ADGroup object you get back contains a SID property which you can use to pass the `IdentityReference` for the access rule:

```
$readGroup  = New-ADGroup -Name $GroupNameRead -DisplayName $GroupNameRead -GroupScope DomainLocal -GroupCategory Security -Path $FSGroupPath -Description "Ger Läs Rättigheter till sökväg: FS\Data\$_" -PassThru
if(-not($readGroup)) # Make sure it got created, if not, handle the error
{
    # Error handling in here
}
else
{
    $accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($readGroup.SID,Read,Allow)
}
```